# Pytest in testing an alert prompt

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I am trying to delete post in a test that fails with error: NameError: name 'window' is not defined. How can I Implement the alert prompt and choose ok, then return to homepage(/)?

````
"""Delete Post"""

def test_delete(client, auth, app):
    auth.login()
    response = client.post('/1/delete')
    assert window.alert("Are you sure?");
    assert response.headers["Location"] == "/"

    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        post = db.execute('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = 1').fetchone()
        assert post is None```
````

Comment: 1. What is window? You need to define the variable. 2. Use try except https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: You can check if response.data has "Are you Sure?" in it with `assert b'Are you sure?' in response.data` but if you want to see if some javascript is getting triggered you need to use a test runner like selenium or playwright.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to test JS `window.alert` in pytest. Unfortunately this is not possible. JS behavior should be tested with JS tools like Jest. Pytest can only strictly test backend behaviors and when testing template rendering, the JS portion of the template is not executed.

It's also possible to test both, backend and frontend behavior, with end-to-end test tools like Selenium or Cypress.